Analysis of a deceptively simple infinite product: $f(n) = \prod_{j=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{j^n}\right)$
I am reading the book "An introduction to Infinite Product" by Charles H. C. Little , Kee L. Teo and Bruce van Brunt (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-90646-7). The book mentions the following result:

$$\prod_{j=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{j^2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

I am currently interested in the generalization: $$f(n) = \prod_{j=2}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{j^n}\right)$$ for integer $n > 2$. This is because when I put the product in WolframAlpha, I received a range of interesting results. Specifically, I put $n = 3$ to $n = 10$ into $f$ to see what came out. With $f(n) = \frac{f_u(n)}{f_d(n)}$, the results I received are



$n$
$f_u(n)$
$f_d(n)$




$3$
$\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)$
$3\pi$


$4$
$\sinh(\pi)$
$4\pi$


$5$
$1$
$\prod_{j=1}^4 \Gamma(2 + (-1)^{j+1}(-1)^\frac{j}{5})$


$6$
$\cosh^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)$
$6\pi^2$


$7$
$1$
$\prod_{j=1}^6 \Gamma(2 + (-1)^{j+1}(-1)^\frac{j}{7})$


$8$
$-\sin((-1)^\frac{1}{4}\pi)\sin((-1)^\frac{3}{4}\pi)\sinh(\pi)$
$8\pi^3$


$9$
$\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)$
$3\pi\prod_{j=1}^8 \Gamma(2 + (-1)^{j+1}(-1)^\frac{j}{9})$


$10$
$\prod_{j=1}^4 \sin((-1)^\frac{j}{5}\pi)$
$2\pi^4(4 + \sum_{j=1}^4 (-1)^{j+1}(-1)^\frac{j}{5})$.



From this (and a few more random plug-values-in-function in Mathematica), I made two possible conjectures:

$f(n)$ (specifically $f_d(n)$ and $f_u(n)$) always have a closed form.
Said closed forms will only involve radical operations (add, minus, multiply, divide), trigonometric functions, hyperbolic functions, principal-branch roots, and the gamma function.

I couldn't find many more functions that has expressions close to this one.
What do you think?

See Mathworld's Infinite Product page, lines 20-27.

Thanks Dan! I also found out that the partial products also have closed forms, which is actually surprising.
